# ie 7 not firing events on dynamically generated markup

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer-7

Got some solved troubles, but want to ask, maybe here is another solution. Here is a situation. 
Got aspx page. With some code behind functions, that get data from DB. Functions called and data returned through JQ in table. Data prepared by server to math html format.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "somePage.aspx/foo",
            data: "{ 'Id' : '" + ID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#brandTable").html(msg.d);
            }
```

Each returned row is looking like this (as is):

```
<tr btcsId='152' id='btcsId_152' onclick='brandClick(9,24,152)'>
<td class='DataGridItem' style='padding:3px; margin:0;font-weight:bolder;'>something<input type='hidden' id='brandID_btcsId152' value='24' brandName='something'/></td>
</tr>
```

table markup:

```
<table class="DataGrid" id="brandTable" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;word-wrap:break-word;" border = "0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    </table>
```

So, the problem was, that event onclick not fired just in ie7. ie8,ie9 works fine. After some thoughts, i decided to add this code immediately afrter table filling. In other words reinit event for each row.

```
$("[id^='btcsId_']").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
    var thisID = $(this).attr("id");
    brandClick(specialityID,$("#"+thisID +" > TD > INPUT").val(),$(this).attr("btcsId"));
    });
});
```

After that it seems work fine. But is it correct? Maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bast way would bo using [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  (jQuery > 1.7) to delegate to your table Element the handling of those events: this works also for elements that are added dinamically

```
$("table#idofYourTable").on("click", "[id^='btcsId_']", function () {
    var thisID = this.id;
    brandClick(specialityID,$("#"+thisID +" > TD > INPUT").val(),$(this).attr("btcsId"));

});
```

Comment: tried this solution. It's work the same as using mine with each. Can't check efficiency. But will rely on your experience.

Comment: @aleha the difference is that you have only one event handler instead of having one event handler for each element: this is the right approach i think

Comment: check this on ie8. Got double event fire,thats not looing good. Must remove native onclick from markup=>modifing .cs code

Answer (score 1):

no it is not correct. you cant bind Click to future element.

Either you write the onclick signature + execution in the element - Or bind it with Live/on(newer)

```
$("[id^='btcsId_']").each(function () {
    $(this).live(function () {
    var thisID = $(this).attr("id");
    brandClick(specialityID,$("#"+thisID +" > TD > INPUT").val(),$(this).attr("btcsId"));
    });
});
```

please consider using `On` instead of live.

(>1.7 )

Comment: He was saying that his code was working, the best way is not to do this but use delegate() or on(), i think

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I dont know why his code was working... I told him to use the Live/On  instead.

Comment: forgot to add. Using jquery-1.5.2.min.js

Comment: @RoyiNamir you are reattaching the events just as he was doing before and use live instead of click(). The correct way using live() would be `$("[id^='btcsId_']").live(function(){...});`